# Why can the sigmoid function seen as an estimation for a probability?

Tags: probability, neural-networks

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iT5P4z6Fzj8&feature=youtu.be&list=PL6Xpj9I5qXYEcOhn7TqghAJ6NAPrNmUBH&t=43) the speaker says "*we could interpret the activation of a neuron as estimating the probability that some input $\mathbf{x}$ belongs to the class one*".

I get that the sigmoidal function $\sigma(x)$ is in $[0,1]$ but yet it isn't an actual probability distribution but a [logistic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution). I'm a bit confused about that because it's not too rare that one sees something like

\begin{align*}
p(y = 1\mid x) &= \frac{1}{1+\exp(-x)} \\
&= \sigma(x)
\end{align*}

My question is if somebody could explain to me why this "estimate" indeed *does* make sense.

Comment: A logistic distribution is a probability distribution on the real numbers, with a sigmoid cumulative distribution function.  In fact it is similar to a Gaussian distribution but has different parameters and slightly heavier tails.  This is why *logit* and *probit* analyses produce similar results.  The advantage is that the logistic function has a natural interpretation as the inverse of the log-odds (i.e. *logit*) function

Comment: I don't see that the logistic distribution has much to do with this.  The only probability distribution involved in the problem as stated is that of $y$, which is a Bernoulli distribution.  The role of the logistic function in this problem is not as the probability distribution of anything that appears in the problem. $\qquad$

Comment: Maybe I'll be back and post an answer. Here's a technical point: the inverse of the logistic function is the logit function (long "o" as in "boat" and "g" like the "j" in "jello"): $$ \operatorname{logit}(p) = \log \frac p {1-p}, \text{ for } 0<p<1. $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy The model can be cast as a [latent variable model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#As_a_latent-variable_model) that involves the logistic distribution. Replacing the logistic distribution with a standard Gaussian distribution yields the [probit regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit_model#Conceptual_framework) setting mentioned by Henry.

Comment: @angryavian : Some specificity is needed to make your comment comprehensible.  What is the latent variable and what is the random variable that has a logistic distribution? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Adapting the material in my earlier link to this setting: Let $z=x+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim \operatorname{Logistic}(0,1)$, and let $y = \mathbf{1}_{\{z>0\}}=\mathbf{1}_{\{\epsilon>-x\}}$. Then $p(y=1 \mid x)=p(\epsilon>-x)=1-\frac{1}{1+e^{x}}=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have (as noted in comments)
$$
\operatorname{logit}(p) = \log \frac p {1-p} \quad \text{for } 0<p<1.
$$
This approaches $+\infty$ as $p\uparrow1$ and approaches $-\infty$ as $p\downarrow0$.

We will observe many independent copies of a random variable $Y$ that is always equal to $0$ or $1$.

Let $H$ be some hypothesis under which the probability that $Y=1$ is larger than the corresponding probability under the hypothesis that $(\text{not }H)$, i.e. we have
$$
\Pr(Y=1\mid H) > \Pr(Y=1\mid \text{not } H).
$$
Then each time we observe $Y=1$, the probability of $H$ increases and each time we observe $Y=0$, the probability of $H$ decreases.  Now observe the identity
$$
\operatorname{logit} \Pr(H\mid Y=1) = \operatorname{logit} \Pr(H) + \log \frac{\Pr(Y=1\mid H)}{\Pr(Y=1 \mid \text{not } H)}.
$$
Thus every time we see $Y=1$, **the logit of the probability of the hypothesis increases by the SAME amount.** And every time we see $Y=0$, the logit decreases by the same amount (but not in general the amount by which it increases when we see $Y=1$).

Since the logit function is the inverse of the logistic function, every increase of $1$ unit in the value of the variable you called $x$ also causes the logit of the probability of $H$ to increase by the same amount.  The model is
$$
\operatorname{logit}\Pr(Y=1) = \alpha + \beta x.
$$
This makes the value of $x$ increase at the same rate as the number of times we observe $Y=1$.

More later maybe$\,\ldots$

Comment: WOW! Thank you sir.